# What are the arguments of 结合？

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence:

某酒类品牌的成功，在于它紧紧抓住都市文化的特点，将产品创新同城市文化、都市人怀旧心态紧密结合，大大提升了酒的档次，创造了酒的新概念。

Sometimes, no often, I get confused with Chinese, especially when sentences use 将 or 把。I rewrote the part I am not sure of. Did I catch the meaning properly?

将产品创新同城市文化、都市人怀旧心态紧密结合

Change to

产品创新紧密结合了城市文化和都市人的怀旧态度，

Comment: Yes you did catch the meaning properly.

Comment: [“把”字句的形式和用法](http://www.thn21.com/base/xiu/9421.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would explain the usage of 将 like this:

将 + Object + AdverbialPart.

AdverbialPart = InfiniteVerb + ResultOfAction

The AdverbialPart is often in the form of sort of a perfect aspect of the verb.

For example: eaten = 吃掉, where 吃 is the basic form of the verb, and 掉 means the action has finished, i.e. perfect aspect. And most basic way to construct it is adding 了 behind the action. Which will give us 把/将XX吃掉/了.

However, some words themselves can be used to express perfect aspect or you can say their perfect forms are the same as their original forms. 结合 is one of those. So you can say Subject + 把/将 + Object1 + 和 + Object2 + [相] + 结合

Regarding your change to the sentence, I think it's alright, but there might be some subtle difference that I will try to illustrate with following translations in English

> 将产品创新同城市文化、都市人怀旧心态紧密结合
>
> ...combined product innovation tightly with urban culture and metropolis dwellers' nostalgic mentality.
>
> 产品创新紧密结合了城市文化和都市人的怀旧态度
>
> Product innovation combined urban culture and metropolis dwellers' nostalgic mentality.

So you see, the subject and object have changed during the transform. Product innovation was one of the object, or I'd say the primary object of the combination action. And in the transformed sentence, it became the subject. It became "combinor", but not necessarily "combined".

And the arguments of 结合 is a list of objects which can be separated by "、" and other parallel conjunction such as 和、与、以及.

```
结合<Object1>、<Object2>、 ... 和<ObjectN>。

把<Object1>、<Object2>、...和<ObjectN>结合。
```

Also same as in English, 结合 could be either active or passive action.

Comment: If ‘结合‘ has 3 objects, is there nobody actually doing  the ‘结合’？？ Things do not just spontaneously unite. Or is it '某酒类品牌的成功  紧密地 结合了 产品创新 同/和 城市文化、都市人的怀旧心态‘